# building a network visualization, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'vx' on string

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i'am trying to build a visualization of relations. I found a great example (https://bl.ocks.org/heybignick/3faf257bbbbc7743bb72310d03b86ee8) and tried to adapt it. But i'm stucked.

First i make the example work with version 5 and then I loaded my own data.
The Data of the original looked like:

```
the links:
{source: "Napoleon", target: "Myriel", value: 1}
the nodes:
{id: "Myriel", group: 1}
```

my own:

```
the links:
{source: "17", target: "1", id: "17"}
the nodes
{id: "1", username: "Nathan Broderick"}
```

I really try to make my data look similiar.

But i always get these errors

```
mis.html:115 Error: missing: 514
    at Ea (d3.v5.min.js:2)
    at l (d3.v5.min.js:2)
    at Function.s.links (d3.v5.min.js:2)
    at mis.html:98
    
d3.v5.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'vx' on string '514'
    at s (d3.v5.min.js:2)
    at d3.v5.min.js:2
    at uo.each (d3.v5.min.js:2)
    at l (d3.v5.min.js:2)
    at s (d3.v5.min.js:2)
    at dr (d3.v5.min.js:2)
    at pr (d3.v5.min.js:2)

d3.v5.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'vx' on string '514'
    at s (d3.v5.min.js:2)
    at d3.v5.min.js:2
    at uo.each (d3.v5.min.js:2)
    at l (d3.v5.min.js:2)
    at s (d3.v5.min.js:2)
    at dr (d3.v5.min.js:2)
    at pr (d3.v5.min.js:2)

(.... and so on)
```

this is my code:
mis.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .links line {
    stroke: #999;
    stroke-opacity: 0.6;
  }

  .nodes circle {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }

  text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>
//get my data and the old data for comparing
  var graphes = [
    d3.json("miserables.json"),
    d3.json("http://localhost:8888/mai20/getlinks.php"),
    d3.json("http://localhost:8888/mai20/getusers.php")
  ]

  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

  Promise.all(graphes)
    .then(function (allData) {
      //my data
      var relas = allData[1];
      var users = allData[2];
      //the old data
      var graph = allData[0];


       //log to compare
       console.log(relas[0])
      console.log(graph.links[0])

      console.log(users[0])
      console.log(graph.nodes[0])

      var link = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "links")
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(relas)
      //  .data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("stroke-width", function (d) { return 1; });
        //changed stroke width
//.attr("stroke-width", function (d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

      var node = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(users)
       // .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("g")

      var circles = node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.group); })
        .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

      //var lables = node.append("text")
      var lables = node.append("text")
        .text(function (d) {
          return d.id;
          //return d.id;
        })
        .attr('x', 6)
        .attr('y', 3);

      node.append("title")
      .text(function (d) { return d.id; });

      simulation
        .nodes(users)
//        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);

      simulation.force("link")
      .links(relas);

//      .links(graph.links);

      function ticked() {
        link
          .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
          .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
          .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
          .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

        node
          .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
          })
      }
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })

  function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }

</script>
```

I have no idea how to solve my Problems :(  perhaps someone can help me.

Comment: Generally you should see this error when you aren't using objects for all nodes. The force layout sets properties, including vx, for each node. Try  logging `users` and making sure that it is an array of objects and parsed correctly, if you could share the result, it might make an answer easier.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. By logging the data i found out, that the problem was, that there where some links to user, which didn't exist anymore... so it helped to clean up my data. :)